# Slick 3 Postgresql void function raw sql

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have a function defined in postgresql db which return void and makes an update inside the function.

when I do

```
Await.result(db.run(sqlu"""select function_name()"""), Duration.Inf)
```

I get this SlickException

```
Update statements should not return a ResultSet
```

Is there a way to call a function which returns void without getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to 
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html

`sqlu`expects a row count, since it returns `DBIO[Int]`, so even if slick would recognize `void` it probably still would throw an exception.
Apparently slick interprets `void` as `ResultSet` and so you could give `sql` a try, which returns a `ResultSet` and just ignore the returned result:

```
Await.result(db.run(sql"""select function_name()"""), Duration.Inf)
```